# Right Click on Column or Row does not show Context Menu

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have the following issue: When right clicking in a row or column in Excel 2010 no menu is appearing. In Excel 2003 right clicking in a row lets you insert/delete rows.

Do you know if this functionality does not exist in Excel 2010 or if my Excel installation is problematic and what I need to do to resolve this?

Update: I am using Windows 7 64 bit and my Office is the Home and Business Edition.

Comment: We need more information about your system before we can help.

Comment: see updated question, @RandolphWest.

Answer (score 4):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to get to the VBE. 
Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see the immediate window.

Enter the following

```
application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
application.CommandBars("cell").Enabled = True
application.CommandBars("Column").Reset
application.CommandBars("column").Enabled = True
application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
application.CommandBars("row").Enabled = True
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to return to Excel.

Comment: As a total Excel novice, it took me a while to realize that copying and pasting the above lines didn't seem to be enough, I had to manually press enter after each line to have it executed. After that, it restored my context menu, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Start Excel in safe mode and see if the problem persists. It may be an add-in that is stealing the functionality.

To open Excel in safe mode, find an Excel document, and hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when double-clicking on it. You should be prompted to open in Safe Mode.

---

EDIT: There's a VBA macro you can use from [this site](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-2007-help/704506-right-click-disabled.html), which will apparently restore right-click behaviour:

```
Sub SwitchOnCutAndPaste()

EnableControl 21, True
EnableControl 19, True
EnableControl 22, True
EnableControl 755, True

End Sub

Sub EnableControl(Id As Integer, Enable As Boolean)

Dim CB As CommandBar
Dim CBC As CommandBarControl

For Each CB In Application.CommandBars
    Set CBC = CB.FindControl(Id:=Id, recursive:=True)
    If Not CBC Is Nothing Then CBC.Enabled = Enable
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I opened excel in safe mode and indeed the right click menu appears normally when I select entire rows or columns. However, there is no add-in installed when I open a normal excel. Could it be that an add-in that was previously installed removed the right click menu permanently (possibly with a VBA command)? And if yes, how can I restore it?

Comment: See my revised answer. I can't speak for whether this works, but it's certainly worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but unfortunately it does not work. I ran the macro but no luck. This is very weird. I have been using excel for ages and have not come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to get to the Visual Basic Editor, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see the immediate window, and enter the following:

```
Application.CommandBars("cell").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("row").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("column").Enabled = True
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to return to Excel.

"ply" is the code used to enable right click of worksheet tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the windows profile issue - log in as administrator rename old profile as .old and log in as user to recreate the new windows profile fix the problem.

Comment: That's a rather generic sort of solution and may actually involve more steps than just that that you talk about with newer versions of Windows—even Windows XP had other steps to take to do it properly from the OS side than just renaming the profile. Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete fix across cell, row, column, tab I needed a composite of this:

```
application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
application.CommandBars("cell").Enabled = True
application.CommandBars("Column").Reset
application.CommandBars("column").Enabled = True
application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
application.CommandBars("row").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("Ply").Reset
Application.CommandBars("ply").Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue. It turned out the sheet was password-protected, and I did not have the password. So I just created a new worksheet and pasted there all contents from the protected sheet. It worked. Now I can right-click, change column width, insert etc.